# Observer bias in basic probability theory?

Tags: probability

A digital photoframe has 18 pictures of interest and 56 pictures that are not of interest.  The photoframe displays each picture for 5 seconds.  The pictures are named such that all the 18 pictures of interest are displayed sequentially, followed by by the 56 pictures that are not of interest.  The cycle then repeats itself.

If you randomly look at the digital photoframe, there is a 32.14% chance that you will see a picture of interest.  I get that fully.  However my experience over the past 6 weeks is that when I randomly look at the digital photoframe I see a picture of interest much more frequently than the 32.14% probability.

One explanation is that my mind mainly registers the pictures of interest and if I happen to see a picture that is not of interest, my mind just ignores it.  I don't have any other explanation.  Or is there an *observer bias* that comes into play here?

**TL;DR**
*[Perhaps unnecessary details that may be totally irrelevant to my question]*

*The 18 pictures of interest are of a girl whom I dated very briefly, before she died in a tragic accident.  I haven't gotten over the loss, despite many years having elapsed.  The 56 pictures are just of natural scenery, good viewing in their own right, but not of my interest currently.  Six weeks ago I acquired this digital photoframe and loaded it with the 74 pictures.  It appears to me that every other time I look at the digital photoframe, I see her picture.  I don't believe I am fantasizing that I am seeing her picture, but who knows....*

Comment: It sounds like your question is about psychology, not math.

Comment: @Sandeep I'm not sure of the answer, but if there is a category on stack exchange for 'Best Backstory to a Math Problem,' I'll vote for this

Comment: @Karl - As for asking in Psychology.SE this was cross-posted there at https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/29144/7604 but it was closed for being too personally related.

Answer (score 1):

As @Karl says, there is enough psychology here to make it difficult to answer, particularly since you say, "my experience over the past 6 weeks is that when I randomly look at the digital photoframe I see a picture of interest much more frequently" doesn't have a particular number with it, or even a distribution from which to draw numbers. And even if there were a number, there could be more than one number: a number for how many times you saw a picture of interest, and another number for how many times you *thought* you saw a picture of interest. In any case, I love this question because it is thought provoking, though not because of the mathematics. Perhaps ask on psych.stackexchange, if there is such a thing?

Comment: I haven't studied it yet, but it does seem possible for an ability to apply [Mathematics of Random Events](https://warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/statistics/currentstudents/modules/st3/st342/)

Comment: As for asking in Psychology.SE this was cross-posted there at https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/29144/7604 but it was closed for being too personally related.